# Pass data to console and get the result using selenium(java) web driver(Chrome)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After logging in to the application, open Dev tools->Console. Type key and get the result value. I us the result for further testing. Can this be handled in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptExecutor

It will be something like:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String yourVariable = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return yourScriptYouExecuteInConsole();");
```